# Is the map $1^{(P',P)}$ sending $P$ to $P'$ a quantum channel?

Tags: quantum-operation

Let $\mathscr{P}_n$ denote the $n$-qubit unsigned Pauli operators, and let $P, P' \in \mathscr{P}_n$. On page 10, appendix A of [this arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00111), $1^{(P^{'}, P)}$ is defined as a linear function on $n$-qubit operators that maps $P$ onto $P^{'}$ and other Paulis to 0. It is claimed that $1^{(P^{'}, P)}$ is a channel. As we know, a quantum channel is a completely positive and trace preserving map. We also know that for any non-identity $P\in\mathscr{P}_n$, $\mathit{tr}(P) = 0$. But $\mathit{tr} (I)= 2^n$, so $1^{(P^{'}, P)}$ would seemingly not preserve trace unless $P = P' = I$.

Why is this function considered a quantum channel? Thank you!

Comment: I've only briefly looked at Appendix A but they say "let $1^{(P',P)}$ denote the (generally unphysical) channel". Note the "generally unphysical", I think in this passage the authors are using the word channel to mean just some linear map between operators on one system to another.

Comment: You're right: a quantum channel can't map $I$ to 0. It's possible that you could fix things by saying "maps all non-identity paulis to zero" but I'm not sure if that's well-defined.

Comment: Some people use "channel" for "CP", without the "TP".

Comment: @NorbertSchuch While this is certainly correct, this case is simply a sloppy use of nomenclature. The considered map is not CP except for $P=P'=I$ (its Choi matrix is $\propto P \otimes \bar{P'}$).

Comment: @MarkusHeinrich True, but not primarily for the reason given in the question (i.e. not being trace preserving). I'd say "superoperator" would be a good name.